# Use Database with Phonegap application

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

This can't be a proper question to ask here, but I am a bit confused about How & which database to use with my `phonegap application (made with HTML5 + Javascript+CSS)`
If anyone having any Reference link or any Idea of'

```
How I can use database in this application?
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use sqlite or a server-based one, which can be about anything.

Comment: @dandavis any link for reference?

Comment: google.com/?q=codova%20db ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLite wrapper.

[Plugin Link](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin)

It's very easy to use.

```
// Wait for Cordova to load
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
  var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "my.db"});

  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (id integer primary key, data text, data_num integer)');

    // demonstrate PRAGMA:
    db.executeSql("pragma table_info (test_table);", [], function(res) {
      console.log("PRAGMA res: " + JSON.stringify(res));
    });

    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test_table (data, data_num) VALUES (?,?)", ["test", 100], function(tx, res) {
      console.log("insertId: " + res.insertId + " -- probably 1");
      console.log("rowsAffected: " + res.rowsAffected + " -- should be 1");

      db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("select count(id) as cnt from test_table;", [], function(tx, res) {
          console.log("res.rows.length: " + res.rows.length + " -- should be 1");
          console.log("res.rows.item(0).cnt: " + res.rows.item(0).cnt + " -- should be 1");
        });
      });

    }, function(e) {
      console.log("ERROR: " + e.message);
    });
  });
}
```

Detailed documentation available in the link.

If you need small data to save like few words, then you can use localStorage.

Comment: How can I install SQLite plugin for browser platform application?

Comment: It's supported on ios, android, wp